# Snowflake: how to get the current Unix epoch timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I get the current [Unix epoch timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com/clock) in Snowflake? I could not find any documentation on the same

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [DATEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01'::DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

or  [DATE_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_part.html):

```
SELECT DATE_PART(epoch_second, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

[Supported Date and Time Parts](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts):

> epoch_second
>
> epoch_millisecond
>
> epoch_microsecond
>
> epoch_nanosecond

Comment: Is there any inbuilt function that provides the timestamp instead of computing the datediff every time? In both cases above the output timestamp is epoch timestamp corresponding to the CURRENT_DATE (which is the current time in the snowflake account time zone). So it doesn't give the actual current Unix timestamp which has no timezone info associated with it

Comment: Lukasz's second solution using DATE_PART is the one you are after: SELECT DATE_PART(epoch_second, CURRENT_DATE); It returns the epoch timestamp, which does not have timezone value. It is the number of seconds since  January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013125/132438, as CURRENT_DATE will return the same number all day long

Answer (score 6):

This solution is timezone independent, no math needed:

```sql
alter session set timezone = 'US/Eastern';
select date_part(epoch_second, current_timestamp());
-- 1637194610

alter session set timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
select date_part(epoch_second, current_timestamp());
-- 1637194621
```

Note that `current_timestamp()` returns what you want, while `current_date()` only returns the day (without a time component).